# Display meta data attribute in user profile

Tags: pages

Right now I'm building a simple intranet site.

With the plugin "Next Active Directory Integration" I read out different fields from the AD and write them into meta-attributes.

How can I map these fields to profile fields like birthday or name and surname?

Comment: You mean you just want to know how to store birthday, name and surname? [The User object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User#Public_Properties) (or wp_user table) has first_name and last_name. There isn't AFAIK a standard field for birthday: if you have one then it'll be a user_meta field added by a plugin you have.

Comment: The "Next Active Directory Integration" plugin saves variables like birthday from our Active Directory into wordpress attributes, which I can use.

How can I use/display this attributes (meta data) in my personal profile (http://intranet/members/USERNAME/profile/) as extra fields, like my name or username.

Comment: What's rendering the profile page? Is that using the author template, or is it something else in your theme? You can use `get_the_author_meta()` or `get_user_meta()` on that page. I don't know what the attribute name is for birthday, though - from a quick grep there's no string 'birth' or 'birthday' in the Next Active Directory Integration plugin.